# How do I make a camera rotate around a player in 3rd person perspective in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a camera rotate around the player so that the player is always in the middle of the screen.

I have tried using the `Slerp()` function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;

    public float Speed = 1f;
    public Camera cam;
    public Vector3 offset;
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (target.position - cam.transform.position).normalized;


        Quaternion lookrotation = target.rotation;
        Quaternion playerrotation = target.rotation;

        playerrotation.y = target.rotation.y;
        playerrotation.x = 0f;
        playerrotation.z = 0f;

        lookrotation.x = transform.rotation.x;
        lookrotation.z = transform.rotation.z;
        //lookrotation.y = transform.rotation.y;

        offset.x = -target.rotation.x * Mathf.PI;


        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, playerrotation, Time.deltaTime * Speed);

        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, target.position + offset, Time.deltaTime * 10000);
    }
}
```

It worked but the player wasn't in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will rotate the gameObject it is attached to so as to keep the `Target` gameObject in the center of the screen and so that the camera looks in the same direction as the target.

```
public Transform Target;
public float Speed = 1f;
public Vector3 Offset;
void LateUpdate()
{
    // Compute the position the object will reach
    Vector3 desiredPosition = Target.rotation * (Target.position + Offset);

    // Compute the direction the object will look at
    Vector3 desiredDirection = Vector3.Project( Target.forward, (Target.position - desiredPosition).normalized );

    // Rotate the object
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp( transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation( desiredDirection ), Time.deltaTime * Speed );

    // Place the object to "compensate" the rotation
    transform.position = Target.position - transform.forward * Offset.magnitude;
}
```

Note : Never, never, **never** manipulate the components of a Quaternion unless you **really know what you are doing**. Quaternions don't store the values you see in the inspector. They are complex entities used to represent rotations, with 4 values.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were a lot of help.))

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check at the left side of the answer.

Comment: One more thing, how would I make the camera always stay behind my gameObject? The controls of the player do not correspond with the rotation of the object when my player rotates.

Comment: That's strange, on my side, when the `target` gameObject rotates, the camera moves and rotates so that its forward vector is aligned with the `target`'s forward vector, thus, moving the camera behind the `target`. Are you sure the forward vector of your player is correct?